# controlling with range(var) doens't work properly

Tags: python, loops

my code looks as follows:

```
def rd_parse(w,i,k):
    for r in list(range(k)):
            j = i+1 + i+r + k-1
            if np(w,i,j):
                    return True
            elif v(w,i,j):
                    return True
            elif np(w,i,j) and v(w,j,k):
                    return True
     else:
            return False

def np(w,i,k):
if k == i + 1 and w[i] == "Hans":
    return True
else:
    return False



def v(w,i,k):
if k == i + 1 and w[i] == "isst":
    return True
else:
    return False
```

a possible query:

`w = ["Hans"]
rd_parse[w,0,len(w)
True`

which is my expected result.

now i want to query something more complicated

`w = ["Hans", "isst"]
rd_parse(w,0,len(w))`

which returns `False`

when i use the debugger, i see that my my loop doesnt work properly. it doesnt interate properly over the list given by `list(range(k))`, which is in case of `len(w) = 2` `[0,1,2]`. it only chooses `r=0` and doesn't take any further steps from then.
can anyone point out why that is?

i wish you a convenient evening,

b.

Comment: *unable to delete comment*

Answer (score 1):

`return` returns from the function. Why do you expect the next iteration?

If you want to return True if *any* element matches, only return False when *none* of the elements match. That is, move `return False` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `return False` outside the loop, you return after the first iteration regardless, you can also simplify your functions, you also don't need to and should not call list on range just to iterate over it:

```
def np(w, i, k):
    return k == i + 1 and w[i] == "Hans"


def v(w, i, k):
    return k == i + 1 and w[i] == "isst"


def rd_parse(w, i, k):
    for r in range(k):
        j = i + 1 + i + r + k - 1
        if v(w, i, j) or v(w,j,k):
            return True
        elif np(w, i, j):
            return True
    return False # outside loop
```

if `np(w,i,j)` is False then `np(w,i,j) and v(w,j,k)` could not possibly be True and in contrast if `np(w,i,j)` is True then you never reach any other line.